# capture screen with electron when rendering a web site

Tags: electron, screen-capture

I have an electron application that loads a web page on the internet.
one of the sites main features is the ability to capture screen, it uses the

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true});
```

but obviously, the electron will through the Permission denied because there will be no 'selecting window to capture' popped up to grant any permission to it.

I already check out some articles and saw [desktopCapture](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer)

the problem is, this is happening and running through the web page javascript not my application's code so I don't know how to affect it.

so what should I do to make capturing the screen works in this situation?

Comment: Do you have access over the web page's source code? Can you change it? If yes, this be done easily using `desktopCapture`

Comment: @aabuhijleh unfortunately, no; I have access to the electron and the most I can do is to manipulate web page code through 'preload.js', etc

Comment: I have left an answer that explains how you can do this even if you don't have any kind of access

Comment: @aabuhijleh yeah, I saw that, later today or in a few days, I will test it, thanks for all of the efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` to call Electron's `desktopCapturer` API like shown below. This implementation assumes you have [`contextIsolation`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation) enabled which is the default behaviour in Electron >= 12

```js
// preload.js

const { desktopCapturer, contextBridge } = require("electron");
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const { join } = require("path");

// inject renderer.js into the web page
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const rendererScript = document.createElement("script");
  rendererScript.text = readFileSync(join(__dirname, "renderer.js"), "utf8");
  document.body.appendChild(rendererScript);
});

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("myCustomGetDisplayMedia", async () => {
  const sources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ["window", "screen"],
  });

  // you should create some kind of UI to prompt the user
  // to select the correct source like Google Chrome does
  const selectedSource = sources[0]; // this is just for testing purposes

  return selectedSource;
});

// renderer.js

navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia = async () => {
  const selectedSource = await globalThis.myCustomGetDisplayMedia();

  // create MediaStream
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
        chromeMediaSourceId: selectedSource.id,
        minWidth: 1280,
        maxWidth: 1280,
        minHeight: 720,
        maxHeight: 720,
      },
    },
  });

  return stream;
};
```

Now when this API is called, a stream will be returned to the caller as expected

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true});
```

[I have created a GitHub repo that has a working implementation of this solution](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/override-getDisplayMedia)

Comment: tnx, it helps a lot especially the github repo